# Mixpanel JQL Cors Issue

Tags: cors, axios, mixpanel

I am trying to call mixpanel jql api from localhost and running into a CORS issue.

Here is my call:

```
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql",
      data,
      withCredentials: true, 
      headers: { 
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": 'true',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      auth: {
        username: xxxxxxxxxxx,
      }
    });
    console.log(res.data);

  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

This is the error in the browser:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out they block localhost:

https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004511086-CORS-errors

Comment: Though link is dead, ty for telling us that they block localhost